# Bayes theorem applied to letter frequency for simple substitution ciphers

Tags: bayesian, frequency

Given a message encoded with a simple substitution cipher, I would like to estimate the probability of each letter representing a given letter key, based on letter frequency analysis. I am not as interested in cryptography and letter order (which I understand are more powerful tools) as I am in how to calculate individual letter posterior probabilities, as a personal learning tool.

I had assumed given

$$P(X = a \mid F_{X} ) = \frac{ P(F_X \mid X = a) P(X = a) }{ P(F_X) }$$

That $P(F_X \mid X = a)$ would be the binomial PMF and $P(X = a)$ is $1 \over 26$, however my application is clearly incorrect, as in a message of 2017 characters, with a single occurrence of 'A', and using Peter Norvigs analysis of the Google library, which found the letter 'Z' occurred with a frequency of 0.09%, I arrive at Binomial PMF $Pr(1, 2017, 0.0009) = 0.29554$. Exchanging the values into the formula above I get:

$$\frac{{0.29554} {1 \over 26}}{1 \over 2017} > 1 !!!$$

Where am I going wrong, and how should I calculate the probability that 'A' is being used to represent 'Z'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F_X$ in your example stands for "A occurs once in 2017 characters", so it is not clear why you assigned the value of $1/2017$ to $P(F_X)$.

Instead, it should be
$$ P(F_X) = \sum_{a = A...Z} P(F_X | X=a) P(X=a).$$

In other words it is just the quantity in numerator summed over all possible letters, which guarantees that your result will be smaller than one, and that the sum of probabilities over all letters will be one.